# Cannot use computer on local network as host for anything through wlan

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, router

I have a computer hooked up to my home network via a PCI wifi adapter in my computer. I can connect to the internet successfully and my computer is visible when I check my router's configuration site (you know the one where you get to by putting the ip of your router in your browser. 192.168.0.1 for me).

My problem is that I can't connect to services on that computer. For example, it is an ubuntu server and I have been doing tests with apache2, xrdp, ssh and ftp. I also am working on an mmo game project I am coding and I am unable to access the game's server when I run it from that computer and try to connect to it from another device in my network. Same goes for minecraft and so on.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: can you ping it? maybe there is a firewall running on it e.g. ufw?

Comment: Just figured it out. I had to define the port in the "Virtual Server" section of my router's settings. I never had to do that before but I guess I have to now. Works great though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Some routers separate wireless devices and wired devices from talking to each other, there might be a setting in the router to tweak that.  Seems weird that port forwarding fixed your problem because that sorta implies you're on the other side of the modem.

Comment: It was virtual server port forwarding. It was not just public, I also had to forward a private one which I think was the solution.